# format json for line chart using laravel api and vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, api, vue.js, linechart

I want to change the format of the json data in the fire laravel to be sent to vuejs, I have json data like this,

```
[
 [
  {
    "yearMonth": "January",
    "sessions": 1192908,
    "users": 808010
  },
  {
    "yearMonth": "February",
    "sessions": 2084625,
    "users": 1566430
  },
  {
    "yearMonth": "March",
    "sessions": 1864468,
    "users": 1417904
  }
 ]
]
```

and I want to change the above json data format to be like this

```
label: [yearMonth1, yearMonth2, yearMonth3],
sessions: [session1, session2, session3],
users : [users1,users2,users3]
```

please advise
thank you

Comment: You want to do it on javascript's part of PHP's part?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking to process this in vuejs, the bellow snippet should work

```js
var data = [
 [
  {
    "yearMonth": "January",
    "sessions": 1192908,
    "users": 808010
  },
  {
    "yearMonth": "February",
    "sessions": 2084625,
    "users": 1566430
  },
  {
    "yearMonth": "March",
    "sessions": 1864468,
    "users": 1417904
  }
 ]
];

const processData = array => ({
    label: array.map(i=>i.yearMonth),
    sessions: array.map(i=>i.sessions),
    users: array.map(i=>i.users)
});

console.log(processData(data[0]));
```